# Set Domain dynamically at Google auth2 API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-authentication

I am using auth2 API for Authenticate users email which are showing on authentication popup.

After authentication from google it redirects the user to a success page of my site for further process. 
That's why I need to create a redirect page and set the url to API configuration.
The redirect url also need to set in my Google API account. 
After running the authentication API google matches the redirect url I have given with the url set to the Account.

Note: In Google API account multiple url of multiple domain can be set.

Now Question is, If my Script install in several Domain, I need to set that Domain to the App that I have created and Google Need to allow it.

Comment: If you are talking about Authorized redirect URIs and Authorized JavaScript origins, I think that is the only way and there is no other way to set it (no API/endpoint or dynamically add a domain). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, after authontication there required  a redirect URL. So that user redirect to the domain. I need to set this domain dynamically. It's a WordPress plugin and this will be installed in various domain.